# How to get throughput of traffic send via Gatling?

Tags: apache-kafka, performance-testing, gatling, gatling-plugin, gatling-reports

We are using Gatling to conduct Kafka perf, spike, etc. tests. Out-of-the-box graphs look amazing, but we want to explore them further.

Is it possible to customize Gatling reports to show the throughput of sent messages to Kafka in Kbits/Mbits?

**Reasoning:**

Knowing how many requests are possible in API is great, but in Kafka, the number of requests is a testing server concern, and if we have 30k+ active users, we want to know how much they can load Kafka data-wise. This information should help us identify bottlenecks in Kafka, network or testing server.